# Come si può dire "mettere sotto la pressione" con una parola sola in italiano?

Tags: verbs, single-words, phrases

Ciao a tutti.

In italiano esiste una parola unica che abbia lo stesso significato dell'espressione "mettere sotto la pressione" (nel senso metaforico, ad esempio caricandolo di lavoro)? Se c'è più di un esempio apprezzerei se li indicaste.

Comment: Intendi se esista una parola unica che traduca l'intera espressione?

Comment: Ti riferisci a “mettere sotto pressione”? Nel senso letterale o figurato? Nel primo caso si usa “pressurizzare” (che è un calco dall'inglese non bellissimo ma molto usato). Nel secondo caso la soluzione è meno semplice.

Comment: @DenisNardin credo che ho chiesto la stessissima cosa nella domanda

Comment: @DaG Non so cosa intendi con figurato, ma intendo stressare qualcuno, per esempio chiedendogli più lavoro, etc.

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti: "Letterale" significa nel senso fisico di pressione.

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti Ho provato a chiarire la domanda secondo i tuoi commenti (a me almeno risultava un po' ambigua), se ho frainteso ovviamente correggi pure.

Comment: Fabio: la pressione è una grandezza fisica, e quindi il significato letterale di “mettere sotto pressione” è “creare una differenza di pressione facendola aumentare in un oggetto chiuso” (in genere un aereo o una pentola); quello figurato è quello che hai spiegato.

Answer (score 8):

Per quanto riguarda il carico di lavoro, forse la parole che stai cercando è "oberare".

> Il mio capo mi ha oberato di lavoro per il fine settimana.

Tuttavia anche un molto simile "pressare" può essere usato in più circostanze.

> Mio padre mi sta pressando per dei risultati all'università.
>
> Un mio amico veniva costantemente pressato per soldi da suo fratello.

Answer (score 1):

Anche un semplice "stressare" penso vada bene...

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!